# Line in problem with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, soundcard

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 as my main operating system 3 days ago. Everything works fine, except my sound card. I can listen to my music without any problem, but when it comes to recording through my line in, the sound keeps skipping and I can't set anything through the system configuration menu.

I tried the `aslamixer` command through the gnome console and I still can't get it working.

I'll provide information about cards, devices versions, if I am what additional information I should provide so I can be helped.

Answer (score 3):

I found this little snip of code about two years ago; it enables line-in throughput:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1
```

This disables it: (*It used to work on 10.04 but doesn't work in 12.04*)

```
pactl unload-module module-loopback
```